# Images are not clear - Picasso Android

Tags: android, image, imageview, picasso

I'm using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for downloading images from URL and putting in ImageView. Images are rectangle, but my ImageViews are squares. So I need to use some cropping, because I have spaces on top and bottom.

Without cropping the image is clear:

```
Picasso.with(context)
.load(left.get(pos).getImageName())
.into(ivFrontPageLeftImage);
```

[image]

To fit inside and crop I'm using:

```
Picasso.with(context)
.load(left.get(pos)
.getImageName())
.fit().centerInside()
.into(ivFrontPageLeftImage);
```

[image]

But as you can see the image is not clear, it is blur.
So how can I fit image inside the square (ImageView). Also image need to be clear, not blur?

I download this image, crop it with size 300 x 300 (to be square, i cut from left and right) and [upload](http://oi62.tinypic.com/29y61p3.jpg) it. I use this new image to put in ImageView:

```
Picasso.with(context)
.load("http://oi62.tinypic.com/29y61p3.jpg")
.fit().centerCrop()
.into(ivFrontPageLeftImage);
```

[image]

As you can see image is clear and it is not blur.
How can I do this programmatically? Is it possible with Picasso, or I need other library to do this?

Comment: what is the resolution of the image in question? Are you sure that's not just how it should look?

Comment: Images are 600 x 300. They are blur, but I want to be clear. Is it possible...? What I need to do..?

Comment: I'm getting the same problem. When using fit() and center crop() the image sometimes get blurry. Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment on Lee's answer as I don't have enough reputation. But his answer was correct as I had the same issue. You can also set it in the `ImageView` object by doing the following:

```
imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply center crop on your ImageView instead of the method you are now using.

```
<ImageView
    ...
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```